# Splitting panes for screen and battons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

I have this code I have been working on trying to get these panels split. I want to get one panel for the screen with the text area and another for the buttons. I need help, I got stuck somewhere. I want to make sure that i produce a phone-like interface

Thank you

Here is what I have done

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class Phone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame phone = new JFrame("My First Gui");
        phone.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel jsp1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel jsp2 = new JPanel();

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, true, jsp1, jsp2);

        // splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        getContentPane().add(splitPane);

        jsp1.add(new James());
        jsp2.add(new Doris());

        phone.getContentPane().add(jsp1);
        phone.getContentPane().add(jsp2);

        phone.pack();
        phone.show();

    }
}

class James extends JPanel {

    public James() {

        BorderLayout bb = new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(bb);

        JLabel txt1 = new JLabel("Phone ");
        JTextArea tx1 = new JTextArea(300, 100);

        add(tx1, bb.CENTER);
        add(txt1, bb.NORTH);
        // add(txt1);
        // add(txt2);
        // add(b1);


    }

}

class Doris extends JPanel {

    public Doris() {

        GridLayout grd = new GridLayout(4, 3, 2, 2);
        setLayout(grd);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
        JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
        JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
        JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
        JButton b9 = new JButton("9");
        JButton bs = new JButton("*");
        JButton b0 = new JButton("0");
        JButton bt = new JButton("#");

        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(b3);
        add(b4);
        add(b5);
        add(b6);
        add(b7);
        add(b8);
        add(b9);
        add(bs);
        add(b0);
        add(bt);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    JPanel jsp1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel jsp2 = new JPanel();

    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, true, jsp1, jsp2);

    // splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
    getContentPane().add(splitPane);

    jsp1.add(new James());
    jsp2.add(new Doris());

    //phone.getContentPane().add(jsp1);
    //phone.getContentPane().add(jsp2);
```

1. First you add the jsp1 and jsp2 to the split pane which is ok. Then you add the split pane to the content pane which is also ok.

2  But then you add jsp1 and jsp2 to the content pane which is NOT ok. A component can only have a single parent. If you want the panels to be in the split pane then just add them to the split pane.

```
//phone.show();
phone.setVisible(true);
```

Don't use the show() method it is deprecated. Instead you should use the setVisible() method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Split Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) for more information and working examples.